# Deploy a 2008 R2 BI SSIS package and distribute using Nuget

Tags: ssis, nuget-package

I have an SSIS package that is needed to be used by other products in the firm. 
Is there any way that I can distribute my package as a Nuget package and let them give the table name that the package requires as input through C# code? 
I mean I want them to simply install my Nuget package and then provide input table name through a property I expose and call a simple method that runs the package and populates some other XYZ table.

Has anyone done something like this or any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: umm....is anybody looking at this?